# Replace a subset of pandas data frame with another data frame

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a data frame(DF1) with 100 columns.( one of the column is ID) 
I have one more data frame(DF2) with 30 columns.( one column is ID)
I have to update the first 30 columns of the data frame(DF1) with the values in second data frame (DF2) keeping the rest of the values in the remaining columns of first data frame (DF1) intact.

update the first 30 column value in DF1 out of the 100 columns when the ID in second data frame (DF2) is present in first data frame (DF1).

Comment: Could you give a example ? Are all values of ID of df2 the same?

Comment: the ID values in the DF2 are values that needs to be updated in DF1. 
There are rows in DF2 with different ID values which needs to be updated accordingly in DF1. Keeping the rest of the values in DF1 intact.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Python 3.7 but I see no reason for it not to work on 2.7:

```
joined = df1.reset_index() \
            [['index', 'ID']] \
            .merge(df2, on='ID')
df1.loc[joined['index'], df1.columns[:30]] = joined.drop(columns=['index', 'ID'])
```

This assumes that `df2` doesn't have a column called `index` or the `merge` will fail saying duplicate key with suffix.

Here a slow-motion of its inner workings:

1. `df1.reset_index()` returns a dataframe same as `df1` but with an additional column: `index`
2. `[['index', 'ID']]` extracts a dataframe containing just these 2 columns from the dataframe in #1
3. `.merge(...)` merges with `df2` , matching on `ID` . The result (`joined`) is a dataframe with 32 columns: `index`, `ID` and the original 30 columns of `df2`.
4. `df1.loc[<row_indexes>, <column_names>] = <another_dataframe>` mean you want to replace at those particular cells with data from `another_dataframe`. Since `joined` has 32 columns, we need to drop the extra 2 (`index` and `ID`)

Comment: can you please explain the working of this snippet as well.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This method does not give me the desired results. this is my code :
````if row['ABAN8'] in new_result['ABAN8'].values: 
          col_df = new_result.loc[new_result['ABAN8'].isin([row['ABAN8']])] 
          joined = new_result.reset_index()[['index', 'ABAN8']].merge(col_df, on='ABAN8')
 new_result.loc[joined['index'], new_result.columns[:95]] = joined.drop(columns=['index', 'ABAN8'])````